# How do you tweak your Storage rules to fit your app?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Premise:
These the rules currently

```
       rules_version = '2';
   service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
   }
 }
}
```

When I run the above rules, not all users's image gets displayed. I don't know if it is because all users are on 1 phone (I test with my own, logout, and log in, rinse and repeat) but I doubt it. There is something in those rules (specifically the auth! not nil part) that makes not all images return.
I say that because with below rule, each user gets an image (albeit not always the one he uploaded because the rules allow anything, nevertheless it shows that the code can fetch images to all users from firebase).

```
     rules_version = '2';
    service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
 }
 }
```

Here is the code to fetch the images from firebase.

```
class homepage: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]
    let lat = locValue.latitude
    let lon = locValue.longitude
    dict = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    print("dict", dict)
    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {       databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)   
    }  
}
```

.....

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]
    let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    cell.lblName.text = person.Education
    cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID
    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }
    return cell
}
```

......

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self
   ........      
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.people.removeAll()
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {   
                    if people.key != thisUsersUid {
                        print("peoplekey",people.key)
                    let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
                    let peopleimageDownloadURL = peopleObject?["imageDownloadURL"]  as? String

                            let peopl = Userx(............PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, .........)

                    self.people.append(peopl)

                        } else {
                            print ("145454")
                        }
                                    } else {
                                                                                                   print ("alphaaa")                                                                                                                                       
                     }

}
            self.people.sort { ($0.distance ?? 0) < ($1.distance ?? 0) 
}
                                  print("aaaaaaaa", self.people.map {$0.distance})        
                                  self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }     
    })
```

....

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) {
    self.image = nil
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.image = image
        })

    }).resume()
}}



  }
```

Comment: I had a smiliar problem, and a database / user reset helped me

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim how do you do that? I had already tried deleting all users in authentication and database.

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim Can you explain what a database / user reset is?

Comment: The first set of rules in the question are the default rules for Storage and only allow authenticated users to access Storage so only auth'd users will see their images. The second set allows *anyone* full access to Storage, so any person, auth'd or not can read their images. Now that's been said, can you clarify what you're asking or what the specific issue is? Also, code formatting and length is a requirement here on SO so please take a moment and condense your code and format it so it's readable. Tons of empty lines are not needed.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the comment. Basically if I use the crazy unsecure settings and run the app, there are images next to each user (albeit not always the right ones). When I run the app with the default settings there are not images next to each users. I don't know if that is because the phone viewing the page is the same phone that created all users who should have their names and images displayed. I suspect this is firebase settings issue because the unsecure build produces images next to each user.

Comment: The wrong pics showing up for each user will have nothing to do with rules. They only control what data can be accessed. If a user picture is the wrong one, that's directly due to the code loading the incorrect image either from Storage or from your tableView dataSource. I would suggest adding a breakpoint in your tableView delegate and step through it and see what the vars populate with as the cell is being populated. I am also going to suggest NOT hitting the internet as you're populating the cells as it's going to be slow and cause a poor UI experience for the user - load then first.

Comment: @Jay thanks. what do you meant by not hitting the internet? Also, for the other problem that is related to the rules (ie not populating any images for users), do you have an idea what's wrong there?

Comment: Tableviews need to be fast; code used within `cellForRowAt` should be as brief as possible. It appears you may be 'hitting the internet' with this code `immy.sd_setImage(with: url) ` to download the picture for the internet every time the cell is refreshed. If not, and you are loading it from the local dataSource then you are all set. As far as the error goes, the code is really hard to read because it's not formatted and quite long. Please format the code and take a moment to review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay thanks for answering. Hmm I am not sure it hits the internet cause performance is quite good. I read the link you provided and have taken out code that is probably unnecessary. For formatting, other than individual code blocks, how does it need to be formatted further? I usually do cmdA and ctlL.

Comment: Where would you put `immy.sd_setImage(with: url)` otherwize?

Comment: Actually that's probably not the issue. However, the code formatting in the question makes it really hard to read and understand what's going on, and objects are being referenced that don't exist in the viewDidLoad with `let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String`. Please format your code, clarify the question and ensure the code is a minimal, complete and verifiable example as I mentioned previously.